# AWS CloudFront viewer request lambda@Edge => to S3 bucket works but no S3 content delivered to browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

> Cloudfront with custom domain to access S3 bucket

I can access [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com) through Cloudfront and S3 delivers Angular content, which loads website just fine.

> Add Viewer Request Lambda@Edge

If I add the following simple function, the Angular App loads just fine still.

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const cf = event.Records[0].cf;

  return cf.request;
};
```

But the point of the lambda function is to check if the user is Authorized. If not, then redirect to Cognito Hosted UI.

So the function successfully does the following:

- Checks if header has authorization
- If not, redirects to Cognito hosted UI.

This part works 4.0

Then the user signs in to Cognito and then redirects back to [www.my-domain.com?code=cognito-access-code](http://www.my-domain.com?code=cognito-access-code)

Here are my thoughts about what happens next.

When cognito redirects back to [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com) with the access code, the lambda@edge should fire with the viewer request.

So I have the lambda check for the query string param "code", if it's there, the function just passes on the request because I want the S3 app to load now.

As in the function just returns cf.request.

When the web app fully loads, it then takes the access code and fetches the access token as expected by AWS Cognito code flow, if I could get it to load the app that is.

So my asumption is that when the Cognito redirects, and my lambda just passes on the cf.request, the app should load just like the simple lambda example in the beginning.

But it doesn't. The redirect occurs and the browser shows the [www.my-domain.com?code=cognito-access-code](http://www.my-domain.com?code=cognito-access-code) but the Angular app from the S3 bucket is not present. As in none of the files are there. No console errors either.

> Here is the lambda@edge viewer request code

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const cf = event.Records[0].cf;
    const token = (cf.request.headers.authorization || [{value: null}])[0].value;
    const isLoginPath = cf.request.uri.startsWith('/login');

    const code = /code/ig.test(cf.request.querystring);


    if (code)
    {
        // This is where it should just pass on to S3 and the app should load but does not
        return cf.request;
    }
    else if (token)
    {
        const publicKeys = await Axios.default.get(keysUrl);
        const JWKS = Jose.createLocalJWKSet(publicKeys.data);

        try
        {
          const { payload } = await Jose.jwtVerify(token, JWKS,
          {
              issuer: `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${cognitoUserPoolId}`
          });

            if (payload.client_id === CLIENT_ID)
            {
              return cf.request;
            }
            else
            {
                return authRedirectResponse;
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            return authRedirectResponse;
        }
     }
    else
    {
        // user has no auth yet. Redirect to auth
        return authRedirectResponse
    }
}
```

NOTE: Added Response object

```
const authRedirectResponse = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: LOGIN_URL,
            }],
        },
    };
```

When the redirect occurs from a successful Cognito login, the only thing in the page is

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Just blank content.

Source tab has nothing.

No console errors.

No Angular app.

It is something with the Cognito redirect. Perhaps my assumption that it hits the lambda again is not correct.

I also have cacheDisabled for now on the Lambda.

**UPDATE ONE**

I have noticed, that if I hit my-domain.com using postman
without toke, I get the Cognito UI
and if I add the token, I get the Angular app.

The issue really seams to be that when Cognito redirects from a successful sign in, that it opens the browser at the assigned redirect_url WITHOUT hitting the cloudfront my-domain.com lambda edge again.

So the browser has nothing to render, no app. It's just the blank page.

**UPDATE TWO FINAL FIX**

During the TS of this issue, I gutted the lambda but kept the bug accidentally. MarcC you were on it (shoutout).

The lambda code was looking for items in the url or header Authorization, if it did not have this, then redirect to Cognito.

That works for the initial login.

User hit's domain, gets redirected to Cognito, logs in and get's redirected (302) by Cognito back to domain.

The final issue was that the redirect for a code auth flow had a query string of ?code=12345, which would status 200 as it would pass the lambda.

Then the s3 bucket or cache would attempt to download the application as in

main.js, polyfill.js, css, etc...

None of these requests would have the Authorization or query string, so they would be redirected by the lambda back to Cognito url, which since we had a valid code, would then redirect back to domain.

This resulted in the browser trying to get files through the Cognito url.

Browser console log was something like

"Access to script at 'https:my-domain/login/to/cognito' (redirected from 'https://my-domain.com/main.js') from origin 'https://my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-origin' header is present on the request resource."

This led down a rabbit hole of cors and policies that were not correct.

What triggered the conclusion was the "Initiator" tab in the network console, where it had the "Request initiator chain"

and showed

```
https://auth.my-domain.com/login/cognito/url
    https://my-domain.com/?code=12345
        https://my-domain.com/main.12345.js
            https://auth.my-domain.com/login/cognito/url
```

Comment: you might add traces and check the lambda logs to validate your assumptions.
you should also add the definition of your authRedirectResponse.

Comment: shouldn't you add a callback URL to your redirect? so Cognito can redirect to your application after a successful sign in, I guess it is included in your `LOGIN_URL`.

Comment: Cognito already does that for me.

Comment: Sorry to ask but do you confirm that on successful signin Cognito returns a 302 with your URL and a code parameter and that's the URL displayed in your browser at the end?

Comment: Cognito does return a redirect with ?code=123445

Comment: Ok then most probably your function didn't behave as expected, did you add logs and checked cloudwatch in the appropriate region?

Comment: Function works 4.0. Currently, I have it down to an issue with CORS on the Cognito redirect.

Comment: Interesting I’m looking fwd for a summary of the issue